# Java library to parse DNS response UDP packet?

Tags: java, sockets, dns, udp

I am writing an assignment for a networking course at university, where I have to manually send a DNS query to a dns server, and then process the response to get the mail servers, IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and a few other things. In the assignment spec it says I am allowed to use any libraries I want to parse the DNS response packet, however I cant seem to find one for Java.

I am sending my DNS request and getting the response like this:

```
int port = 53;
    dnsIP = "8.8.8.8"; // TODO HARDCODED

    DatagramSocket socket;
    // DNS REQUEST
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeShort(0x1234);

    // Write Query Flags
    dos.writeShort(0x0100);

    // Question Count: Specifies the number of questions in the Question section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0001);

    // Answer Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Answer section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);

    // Authority Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Authority section of 
    // the message. (“NS” stands for “name server”)
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);

    // Additional Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Additional section of the message.
    dos.writeShort(0x0000);        

    String[] domainParts = hostName.split("\\.");
    System.out.println(hostName + " has " + domainParts.length + " parts");

    for (int i = 0; i<domainParts.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Writing: " + domainParts[i]);
        byte[] domainBytes = domainParts[i].getBytes("UTF-8");
        dos.writeByte(domainBytes.length);
        dos.write(domainBytes);
    }

 // No more parts
    dos.writeByte(0x00);

    // Type 0x01 = A (Host Request)
    dos.writeShort(0xFF);

    // Class 0x01 = IN
    dos.writeShort(0x0001);

    byte[] dnsFrame = baos.toByteArray();

    System.out.println("Sending: " + dnsFrame.length + " bytes");
    for (int i =0; i< dnsFrame.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("0x" + String.format("%x", dnsFrame[i]) + " " );
    }
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
    DatagramPacket dnsRequestPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length, InetAddress.getByName(dnsIP), port);
    socket.send(dnsRequestPacket);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    DatagramPacket dnsResponsePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
    socket.receive(dnsResponsePacket);
```

However the issue I have is I need to parse the Hex response and retrieve the aforementioned information. I have been looking all morning but I cant seem to find any library capable of parsing this information.

If anyone knows of a good library or a way I can parse it myself I would much appreciate it.

Cheers
Corey

EDIT: here is my full code

```
package coms3200A2;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SpringLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Font;

public class AppHome {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JTextField DNSServerInput;
    private JTextField hostDomainInput;
    JTabbedPane tabbedPane;
    SpringLayout sl_DNSSearch;
    SpringLayout s2_RDNSSearch;

    JPanel DNSSearch;
    JPanel RDNSSearch;
    JLabel DNSServerLabel;
    JLabel hostDomainLabel;
    JButton submitDNS;
    JLabel DNSErrorsLabel;
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    AppHome window = new AppHome();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the application.
     */
    public AppHome() {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the contents of the frame.
     */
    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 1400, 900);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);
        sl_DNSSearch = new SpringLayout();
        s2_RDNSSearch = new SpringLayout();

        DNSSearch = new JPanel(sl_DNSSearch);
        RDNSSearch = new JPanel(s2_RDNSSearch);

        // TODO TESTING
        DNSSearch.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        RDNSSearch.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        // DNS SEARCH

        tabbedPane.addTab("DNS Search", DNSSearch);

        DNSServerLabel = new JLabel("DNS Server: ");
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, DNSServerLabel, 10, SpringLayout.NORTH, DNSSearch);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, DNSServerLabel, 10, SpringLayout.WEST, DNSSearch);
        DNSSearch.add(DNSServerLabel);

        hostDomainLabel = new JLabel("Host/Domain name: ");
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, hostDomainLabel, 21, SpringLayout.SOUTH, DNSServerLabel);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, hostDomainLabel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, DNSServerLabel);
        DNSSearch.add(hostDomainLabel);

        DNSServerInput = new JTextField();
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, DNSServerInput, -3, SpringLayout.NORTH, DNSServerLabel);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, DNSServerInput, 115, SpringLayout.EAST, DNSServerLabel);
        DNSSearch.add(DNSServerInput);
        DNSServerInput.setColumns(30);

        hostDomainInput = new JTextField();
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, hostDomainInput, -3, SpringLayout.NORTH, hostDomainLabel);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, hostDomainInput, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, DNSServerInput);
        DNSSearch.add(hostDomainInput);
        hostDomainInput.setColumns(30);

        submitDNS = new JButton("Submit");
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, submitDNS, 46, SpringLayout.SOUTH, hostDomainInput);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, submitDNS, 0, SpringLayout.EAST, DNSServerInput);
        DNSSearch.add(submitDNS);

        DNSErrorsLabel = new JLabel("\"errors here\"");
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, DNSErrorsLabel, 83, SpringLayout.SOUTH, hostDomainLabel);
        sl_DNSSearch.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, DNSErrorsLabel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, DNSServerLabel);
        DNSErrorsLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        DNSErrorsLabel.setForeground(Color.RED);
        DNSSearch.add(DNSErrorsLabel);

        // REVERSE DNS SEARCH
        tabbedPane.addTab("Reverse DNS Search", RDNSSearch);

        frame.getContentPane().add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        submitDNS.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    processDNSSearch(DNSServerInput.getText(), hostDomainInput.getText());
                } catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();

                    DNSErrorsLabel.setText("Error: " + e2.getMessage());
                }

            }
        });
    }

    private void processDNSSearch(String dnsServer, String hostName) throws IOException {
        String dnsIP = dnsServer;
        int port = 53;
        dnsIP = "8.8.8.8"; // TODO HARDCODED

        DatagramSocket socket;
        // DNS REQUEST
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
        dos.writeShort(0x1234);

        // Write Query Flags
        dos.writeShort(0x0100);

        // Question Count: Specifies the number of questions in the Question section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0001);

        // Answer Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Answer section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);

        // Authority Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Authority section of 
        // the message. (“NS” stands for “name server”)
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);

        // Additional Record Count: Specifies the number of resource records in the Additional section of the message.
        dos.writeShort(0x0000);        

        String[] domainParts = hostName.split("\\.");
        System.out.println(hostName + " has " + domainParts.length + " parts");

        for (int i = 0; i<domainParts.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Writing: " + domainParts[i]);
            byte[] domainBytes = domainParts[i].getBytes("UTF-8");
            dos.writeByte(domainBytes.length);
            dos.write(domainBytes);
        }

     // No more parts
        dos.writeByte(0x00);

        // Type 0x01 = A (Host Request)
        dos.writeShort(0xFF);

        // Class 0x01 = IN
        dos.writeShort(0x0001);

        byte[] dnsFrame = baos.toByteArray();

        System.out.println("Sending: " + dnsFrame.length + " bytes");
        for (int i =0; i< dnsFrame.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("0x" + String.format("%x", dnsFrame[i]) + " " );
        }
        socket = new DatagramSocket();
        DatagramPacket dnsRequestPacket = new DatagramPacket(dnsFrame, dnsFrame.length, InetAddress.getByName(dnsIP), port);
        socket.send(dnsRequestPacket);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        DatagramPacket dnsResponsePacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
        socket.receive(dnsResponsePacket);

        System.out.println("\nReceived: " + dnsResponsePacket.getLength() + " bytes");
        for (int i = 0; i < dnsResponsePacket.getLength(); i++) {
            //System.out.print(" 0x" + buffer + " " );
            System.out.print(" 0x" + String.format("%x", buffer[i]) + " " );

        }
        System.out.println("\n");



        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
        System.out.println("Transaction ID: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Flags: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Questions: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Answers RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Authority RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Additional RRs: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));

        int recLen = 0;
        while ((recLen = din.readByte()) > 0) {
            byte[] record = new byte[recLen];

            for (int i = 0; i < recLen; i++) {
                record[i] = din.readByte();
            }

            System.out.println("Record: " + new String(record, "UTF-8"));
        }

        System.out.println("Record Type: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Class: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));

        System.out.println("Field: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Type: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("Class: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readShort()));
        System.out.println("TTL: 0x" + String.format("%x", din.readInt()));

        short addrLen = din.readShort();
        System.out.println("Len: 0x" + String.format("%x", addrLen));

        System.out.print("Address: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < addrLen; i++ ) {
            System.out.print("" + String.format("%d", (din.readByte() & 0xFF)) + ".");
        }
    }

}

enter code here
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you look at `dnsjava` (http://dnsjava.org/)? It is a high level DNS client but you may be able to directly reuse its inner part for just packet parsing per your need.

It makes little difference in parsing if your packet came from UDP or TCP.
If you look at `Record.java` there are various `fromWire` methods that may be useful. See also the `utils/` directory and the `DNSInput.java` file.

Otherwise go back to the specification: [RFC1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) section 4 gives you all details on how a message is formatted. It is the same structure in both directions. In your specific case you will need to poke at the "Answer" part. Make sure not to forget about name compression, as outlined in §4.1.4.